# Could not play video in the path (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com...)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, internal-storage

I have saved my video internally on the phone with the following code :

```
public static void DownloadVideo(Context context, String URL) {

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(URL));
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat videoName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd_HHmmss");
        String strDate = videoName.format(date);
        request.setDescription("Setting up the AR");
        request.setTitle("AR setup ...");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        }

        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, "/NewVisionARVideos/", "" + strDate + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");

        System.out.println("count  files  --- " + context.getExternalFilesDir(null).listFiles());

        for(int i = 0; i < context.getExternalFilesDir(null).listFiles().length; i++){

            System.out.println("** each file -- " + context.getExternalFilesDir(null).listFiles()[i]);
        }

        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);

    }
```

This I what I have added in the manifest file :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is the path am pointing to load the video :

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.shliama.augmentedvideotutorial/files/NewVisionARVideos/test.mp4";
```

Below is the error am getting when I try to play the video in the media player. The path is correct and I have enabled the permissions in the manifest and the phone as well.

Below is the error am getting :

```
D/ArVideoFragment: playbackVideo = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.shliama.augmentedvideotutorial/files/NewVisionARVideos/test.mp4
E/ArVideoFragment: Could not play video [/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.shliama.augmentedvideotutorial/files/NewVisionARVideos/test.mp4]
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.shliama.augmentedvideotutorial/files/NewVisionARVideos/test.mp4
```

Is there another way of playing a video in the android `MediaPlayer` ?

EDIT:

Actually, found out that I was pointing to the assets folder since I was following this [blog](https://medium.com/krootl/arcore-sceneform-simple-video-playback-3fe2f909bfbc) post.

This is method which points to the assets folder
https://gist.github.com/huxaiphaer/268b94a0e7959822fa679a7523701187

Comment: Have you checked for yourself if the file exists at that path? Are you on Android Q? You do not need any permission for getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: Yes am using Android 10 (Q), @blackapps, and even the video is available in the same path. What could be done wrong now ?

Comment: On Android Q that path is not only app specific but invisible for other apps. Hence when MediaPlayer is a different app...

Comment: By the [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer), I mean the Android one .

Am working on an AR stuff whereby if I scan an Image the video is played, videos were working when they were stored in the project, so I resorted to shift them on an Internal storage, so the MediaPlayer doesn't play them. with a FileNotFoundException. Yet it's available in the path.
So what's the best way of accessing videos form internal storage ? @blackapps

Comment: I dont know. Can it play from an uri? Then use FileProvider to serve your file.

Comment: @blackapps, I think I got a clue , the code am using it still points to the assets folder of the project, maybe can you help me and point to the path below:

`getExternalFilesDir(null)`

below is the code for the function which am talking about:

https://gist.github.com/huxaiphaer/268b94a0e7959822fa679a7523701187

Comment: `the code am using it still points to the assets folder ` ??? Did you use other code than posted? Unforgivable!

Comment: Let me update my question @blackapps, but just found it out, since I was following a certain AR blog post

Answer (score 0):

**I Think**, you are not getting your external Storage directory properly.

**Use This**

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "Android/data/com.shliama.augmentedvideotutorial/files/NewVisionARVideos/test.mp4");
```

check your path properly dose it right and check you video also.